# jQuery UI datepicker reinitialize after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, yii, datepicker

I'm using Yii and it's jQuery UI Datepicker widget.

I use it in CGridView filtering options. When CGridView finishes ajax call it will call `afterAjaxUpdate` event.

Problem is that I have this JUI Datepicker with custom settings all around my web, so I can't just do `$('.picker').datepicker();` because all previous options will be lost.

Is there any way to reinitialize JUI Datepicker with same options?

**html.php | extends CHtml**

```
public static function datePicker($options) {
   return Yii::app()->controller->widget(
        'zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',
        CMap::mergeArray(
            [
                'class' => 'picker',
            ],
            $options
        ),
        true
    );
}
```

**view.php**

```
$this->widget(
     'ext.GridView',
     [
         'columns' => [
             [
                  'name' => 'date',
                  'filter' => Html::datePickerField([
                      'name' => 'Model[date]',
                  ]),
             ],
         ],
     ]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a function for assigning datepicker to your desired fields:

```
<script>
    function setDatePicker()
    {
         $('.picker').datepicker({
            //Your desired options
         });
    }
</script>
```

Then, call this function on `afterAjaxUpdate` in every gridview:

```
'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'js:function(){setDatePicker();}'
```